# How to check in a .framework file in a Xamarin iOS Bindings Library correctly?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I successfully created a Xamarin Bindings Library from a native Framework in iOS. For using the .framework files you have to set a native Reference to them. So far everything works fine.

The IDE (in this case Visual Studio for Mac) handles .framework files like folders. If i copy the .framework file into the project and then check it in this works.
But when i then upload the app containing the bindings project to the Apple App Store my app gets rejected because Apple says there is code for which i don't have a valid certificate: a.k.a the .framework file.
Now if i don't check the .framework file in, the bindings project always looks for a reference on my Mac, which is also not the way to go on.

My question is now how do i check this .framework file into Version Control and still be able to upload my app to the App Store?

I couldn't find anything related to this specific matter, only how to create binding libraries. Am i doing something wrong here?